# How to remove click event on table first row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, click

I am try to set click event on table every row with this.

This is table:

```
<table border='1px'>
    <tr>
        <td class='td'>first row frist column</td>
        <td>first row second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='td'>second row frist column</td>
        <td>second row second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='td'>third row frist column</td>
        <td>third row second column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is simple jQuery:-

```
$('table tbody tr  td:nth-child(1)').live('click',function(){
alert($(this).text());
})
```

With this I  click any of first column then on its alert I want to unset table first row column click event.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/CGbXP/4/

Give a class `col+number`  to all column. Then use...

```
var i = 1;
$('td').each(function(){    
    $(this).addClass('col'+i);
    i = i+1;
});

$('table').find("td:not(.col4)").on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: i want to set there second column id... how?

Comment: no no... i want to set first row second column id='second' something like `<tr>
        <td class='td'>first row frist column</td>
        <td id='second'>first row second column</td>
    </tr>`

Comment: you want to disable only on first row - second column?

Comment: actual i have six coumn in every row so i want to remove first row fifth column class.

Comment: good try but i have six column and all have same id='xyz'... so its not possible to set manual id or class

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:not()` pseudo selector to exclude the first row from your click binding.

```
$('table tbody tr:not(:first) td:first-child')
```

This will append a click handler to all first columns, except the first column in the first row. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/rPKSN/2/) is a jsFiddle for the above.

Answer (score 1):

> Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer 
>   better methods that do not have its drawbacks

`.live` is deprecate in latest version of jquery.

Try this

```
$('table tbody tr:not(:first)').on('click',function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KvvQ/)

Comment: i want to set there second column id... how?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    $('table tbody tr:not(:first-child)  td').click(function(){
alert($(this).text());
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pepean/JP9EM/

Answer (score 1):

You can either exclude the first row in your selector right away, by specifying it should only apply to all rows with an index greater than 0:

```
$('table tbody tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(1)').live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

However, in more recent jQuery versions, `.live` has been deprecated and even removed in 1.10, so you should use `.on` instead:

```
$('table tbody tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(1)').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Lastly, in case you should ever have nested tables, your selector will return too many hits. Select the direct children instead:

```
$('table > tbody > tr:gt(0) > td:nth-child(1)').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2FkDY/

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have to give a class on the first row then use the `onclick` event.

```
$('.td').on('click', function() { 
     //do your stuff here

});
```

Hope it helps